# How to make outlined texture in blender?

Tags: texturing, blender-internal-render-engine

How to make outlined edges and not transparent texture in blender? Like on the img below?
[image]

**UPD**

I get this bird beak effect on every edge.Is there a way to remove this?

[image]

**UPD**

I've tried Chaining method and refused from it because it makes the line thiner. See screenshot:

[image]

Also, here are my settings:
Caps are Butt. Edge Types are Edge Mark. No modifiers.

Comment: Hi, please use the question editor's button to load images, if possible, so that 1) they're visible directly in this site and 2) they're permanent, helping future visitors to understand your issue, even if the linked site should expire or change...

Comment: Great! have you ever heard of freestyle? https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/freestyle/index.html this could be perfect for you. Eg: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/freestyle/parameter_editor/line_set.html

Comment: @m.ardito It is great! But, I get this strange effect at the edges. I updated the question with an image. Also, why did I get two minuses for this question?

Comment: I think this is a valid question +1 ... you should also update the question on how you are rendering the edges now (which gives the bird beak effect).

Comment: @ArthurK. I didn't DV this question, but even in the edited form, you're really saying next to nothing about what you have and what you tried... not sharing details, that's sufficient imho for someone to find your question not much clear or useful... future readers reading this will not be able to compare what they'll have with your issue, lessening the value of your current question, and that of answers. But, you can still improve it if you want! :)

Comment: @m.ardito I did not mention anything about things that I've tried because I've tried so many. Plus you have to understand that this is my first time that I work in Blender.

Answer (score 1):

I add this to show some example related to your edited question:

You say very little about your object mesh, but it seems you set a linestyle thickness quite high for the overall mesh size.

I try to replicate it here:

[image]

where you can see the corners are not that good but just changing one setting gets  better results:

[image]

of course you have to experiment, to find your best setting, and freestyle really has tons of settings...

Comment: Updated the question with a screenshot.